# Replacing numbers with colours in a dataframe in r

Tags: r, colors, replace

I have the following data.frame

```
df<-data.frame(x=c("A","B","C"),colour=c(0.3,0.6,0.9))

  x colour
1 A    0.3
2 B    0.6
3 C    0.9
```

I want to replace the numbers in df[,"colour"] with colours such that

```
< 0.4 = colour 1 
0.4 - 0.7 = colour 2 
< 0.7= colour 3
```

I have tried the following replacement scheme but the previous colour assignment are replaced with the latter. Any advice?

```
library(RColorBrewer)

g<-brewer.pal(3,"Greens")

col1<-df[,"colour"] < 0.4
df[col1,"colour"]<-g[1]
col2<-df[,"colour"] < 0.7
df[col2,"colour"]<-g[2]
col3<-df[,"colour"] >= 0.7
df[col3,"colour"]<-g[3]
```

Thanks for you advice.

THE SOLUTION
Thanks seancarmody (and spaceman for useful comments)

```
v<-c(0.45,0.65,0.75,0.85,0.95)
breaks<-c(0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9)

#Create a colour for each section
cols<-brewer.pal(length(breaks)+1,"Greens")
#Replace the gsim values with colours using the breaks
v <- as.character(cut(v, c(-Inf, breaks, Inf),labels=cols))

 > v
[1] "#C7E9C0" "#74C476" "#41AB5D" "#238B45" "#005A32"
```

Comment: Because now the >0.5 line is overwriting the >0.7 line done before it. Everything over 0.7 is also over 0.5. Anyway, this sequence of tests is completely the wrong approach, the R way of doing it is by one test on the vector of values.

Comment: @Spacedman Darn. I mistyped. I will update the update the question.

Comment: Actually no I didn't mistype. While everything over 0.7 is also over 0.5 the ordering should take care of the problem

Comment: Ugh. You are replacing SOME of the numeric values with characters. No wonder you get NAs. Really, don't do this, don't even try to do this. I suspect you are just running this code in one go - don't - when you are trying to figure out where something is going wrong do it ONE line at a time, and see what the values of the variables are. Check what df is after your first replacement...

Comment: Again, break it down! What is the value of cut(v, c(0, breaks, 1))? How many levels? How long is your colour vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach will work if you change order:

```
col2<-df[,"colour"] < 0.7
df[col2,"colour"]<-g[2]
col1<-df[,"colour"] < 0.4
df[col1,"colour"]<-g[1]
```

Since everything less than 0.4 is also less than 0.7, your approach was overwriting col1. Since you've edited your original question, the above is out of date. I'd just use the more general approach here:

```
breaks <- c(0.4, 0.7)  # you can add more cut points here
cols <- brewer.pal(length(breaks) + 1, "Greens")
df$colour <- as.character(cut(df$colour, c(-Inf, breaks, Inf), labels=cols))
```

Comment: Your 0 and 1 limits don't agree with the OP - you can use -Inf and +Inf here. Also you can put the colours in as the labels argument to cut, and convert to character if you want.

Comment: @Spacedman thanks for the pointer: I've edited the answer. Elizbeth see if this modified version works.

Comment: @seancarmody I really like the concise nature of your general approach but it seems to generate NAs (see updated question) or am I missing something?